# Ember SelectView not displaying the correct content binding only in Ember-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, jquery-chosen

I made a small mixin for the Chosen plugin that worked well in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/camdub/Xu6UY/) fiddle.

When I use this in my ember-rails application the chosen box shows up, but has no options. I think it is related to my using ArrayController.extend vs Object.create (in the fiddle), but I can't figure out why. When I change extend to create in rails, it tries to create the controller twice and gives an error.

Ember changes so fast, did I miss something from the fiddle version to the ember-rails version?

(ember-rails source code under assets at https://github.com/camdub/watchd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, it seems that you're using the routing. Nice. You understood that when using routing, the controllers are instantiated for you by the framework, and each xxxView has its xxxController instance, accessible by the `controller` property.

in repos.handlebars, try to directly use `controller'.

```
<div class="container top-section">
  {{view Watchd.ChosenSelect
    contentBinding="controller.content"
    valueBinding="controller.selected"
  }}
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, I think that is the right track, but the contentBinding and valueBinding are not part of the repos controller. I'm trying to bind the content and value bindings to another controller (in this case the repos_filter controller).

Comment: This also doesn't work with just the plain Ember.Select view either

Comment: Ok, then I think you can bind on `controller.controllers.reposFilterController`

Comment: Dang. This does not work either. I also tried `controllers.RepoFilterController`. In many of the examples on the emberjs.com docs they use the `App.Controller` syntax, but it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Wait, you were right. It looks like `controller.controllers.repoFilterController` does something, but the UI remains unchanged (no values in select box). The dev tools show 

`Begin: Flush Sync Queue ember-latest.js:3431
  Ember.Binding<ember493>(templateData.keywords.controller.controllers.reposFilterController.selected -> value) <- cam`

Comment: I think I have to install your app, and see what happen. I hope I can do that this evening.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the mixin. I've forked your repo, and play a little. By commenting the templates overrides, the select is populated with the repoFilter.

Comment: well, the other difference between the fiddle and your app, is the ember version. Be carefull of the current context in the templates. see https://github.com/sly7-7/watchd/commit/3306b8fea1c0ec25441ba9e6b12eb11069b61df9 for the modifications, and here for explanations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818116/ember-js-handlebars-displays-nothing/11818157#11818157