# content.name returns empty for collection

Tags: ember.js

I'm starting with ember.js and ran into trouble trying out things in the ember.js docs (http://docs.emberjs.com/symbols/Handlebars.helpers.html#.collection).

This application code:

```
App = Ember.Application.create()
App.items = [
  Ember.Object.create({name: 'Dave'}),
  Ember.Object.create({name: 'Mary'}),
  Ember.Object.create({name: 'Sara'})
]
```

with this template code:

```
{{#collection contentBinding="App.items"}}
    Hi {{content.name}}
{{/collection}}
```

Results in this:

```
<div id="ember122" class="ember-view">    
    <div id="ember142" class="ember-view">    
        <div id="ember149" class="ember-view">  Hi    
            <script id="metamorph-0-start" type="text/x-placeholder">    
            </script>    
            <script id="metamorph-0-end" type="text/x-placeholder">    
            </script>    
        </div>    
        <div id="ember150" class="ember-view">  Hi    
            <script id="metamorph-1-start" type="text/x-placeholder">    
            </script>    
            <script id="metamorph-1-end" type="text/x-placeholder">    
            </script>    
        </div>    
        <div id="ember151" class="ember-view">  Hi    
            <script id="metamorph-2-start" type="text/x-placeholder">    
            </script>    
            <script id="metamorph-2-end" type="text/x-placeholder">    
            </script>    
        </div>    
    </div>    
</div>
```

So, it effectively iterates through the objects, but fails to return the name values for each. Why is this? Are the docs outdated, perhaps? Is there a better way to achieve the desired result (iterating through the items)? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using ember-latest, or 1.0-pre, in this case, you have to prefix `content.name` with `view`. Since 1.0 pre, the retrieval of the context change. see: [Ember.js: Handlebars displays nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818116/ember-js-handlebars-displays-nothing/11818157#11818157) for furhter explanations.

That beeing said, the documentation is not up to date. Could you post a pull request with the fix?

Answer (score 0):

This example work well: http://jsfiddle.net/secretlm/qD6az/3/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It seems to indeed work fine in JsFiddle, but I get the same results running it locally as I did with the original.