# Ember.js Handlebars.helpers.collection not working

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

I'm new to ember and I'm trying to play with the code a bit so I downloaded the starters kit from the website as a starting template.

I'm trying to use the ember handlebars helper for CollectionView, I copy paste the sample code but all I see is "Hi" 3 times without the name:

http://docs.emberjs.com/symbols/Handlebars.helpers.html#method=.collection

what am I doing something wrong?

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#collection contentBinding="App.items"}}
        Hi {{content.name}}
    {{/collection}}
</script>


<script>
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.items = [
    Ember.Object.create({name: 'Dave'}),
    Ember.Object.create({name: 'Mary'}),
   Ember.Object.create({name: 'Sara'})
]
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028209/content-name-returns-empty-for-collection/12028795#12028795

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ember.js: Handlebars displays nothing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818116/ember-js-handlebars-displays-nothing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a problem about the way context is managed in the latest version of ember that is explained at:

[content.name returns empty for collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028209/content-name-returns-empty-for-collection/12028795#12028795)

In summary, you need to do this in your template instead:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#collection contentBinding="App.items" }}
        Hi {{view.content.name}} 
    {{/collection}}
</script>​
```

Fiddle showing it: http://jsfiddle.net/XdHRS/

For the same purpose you could just use each:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#each App.items }}
        Hi {{name}} 
    {{/each}}
</script>​
```

Fiddle showing it: http://jsfiddle.net/e3UTt/13/