# ember.js view example from docs

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, view, ember.js

I'm new to Ember and I try to execute all examples from the documentation. But I found, that some of them won't work.
For example, in the 'Building a View Hierarchy' section. I try to execute the first example, but I don't see InfoView data ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LMnet/EX8HY/)). But if I add 'view' before data, like this:

```
<b>Posts:</b> {{view.posts}}
<br>
<b>Hobbies:</b> {{view.hobbies}}
```

All template looks fine ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LMnet/EX8HY/5/)).
So, what is the point of this 'view' word? In the UserView template I didn't write any prefixes before the data and it works normally.

Comment: This is due to the context. Since few months now, the context of a child view is the context of the parentView. For more information, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818116/ember-js-handlebars-displays-nothing Could you point the doc where you see this ? If the doc does'nt work, then a fix should be submitted.

Comment: Thx, @sly7_7, your link help a lot. This mistake I found on official [Ember doc](http://emberjs.com/documentation/) on 'Building a View Hierarchy' section.

Comment: You're welcome :) I found the mistake, I've submitted a pull request. Thanks