# why view. is needed in handlebars

Tags: ember.js

I can't understand something in Ember.js, my contains a property, but in order to display it i have to do {{view.property}}, why can't I simple use {{property}} ?

in the following example only {{view.test}} is displayed.

shouldn't the view be the default scope ?

index.html:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="places">
    {{test}} {{view.test}}
</script>
```

app.js:

```
App.PlacesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
});

App.PlacesView = Ember.View.extend({
templateName: 'places',
test: 'test'
```

});

Comment: Here have some info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818116/ember-js-handlebars-displays-nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Ember 1.0pre, the context for handlebars helpers in your template has been changed to be the controller.

Before that, it was the view.  The `view` keyword is available to access properties from the view.

Try adding a `test` property to your controller and see what happens.